# Css / Jquery Div Style

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that i have added a border style to. However when I try to add a CSS class to it the div style over rides it.

```
if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '')
        {
            if(!searchReg.test($("#input-whatmask").val())){
                $("#input-whatmask").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
                hasError = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Anyone confirm the correct way / method of doing this ?

Comment: I reckon this belongs to http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: please post the stylesheet for that div and the relevant html-snippets, too.

Comment: please add jdfiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sure your problem is because of the css style precedence. a style for an id (`#input-whatmask`) is more important than one for a class (`.errorinput`) so nothing will change. to correct that, declare your style as `#input-whatmask.errorinput` instead of just `.errorinput` so it will be preferred (id with class is more specific than just id).

to explain how this works exactly (quoting [this great article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)):

> Specificity is calculated by counting various components of your css
>   and expressing them in a form (a,b,c,d). This will be clearer with an
>   example, but first the components.
>
> - Element, Pseudo Element: d = 1 – (0,0,0,1)
> - Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: c = 1 – (0,0,1,0)
> - Id: b = 1 – (0,1,0,0)
> - Inline Style: a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)
>
> An id is more specific than a class is more specific than an element.

Answer (score 0):

Styles in side the div tag, for example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
```

Will override styles from a class attached to the div, for example this div will still have a blue border:

```
<div class="myClass" style="border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
```

...

```
.myClass
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

However this div will have a red border:

```
<div class="myClass" style="border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
```

...

```
.myClass
{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

See this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtVRK/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this

```
if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '')
{
    if(!searchReg.test($("#input-whatmask").val())){
        $("#input-whatmask").attr("class","errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
        hasError = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you use attr() instead of addClass() then the styles are override. attr() change the oldclass name to newClass name and addClass() just add the newClass to oldClass.

`or`

use `!important` for a property which has to be override in newCalss with your same code

`or`

```
if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '')
    {
        if(!searchReg.test($("#input-whatmask").val())){
            $("#input-whatmask").removeClass("oldClass").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```